MongoDB Atlas private link Not working in Java SDK

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path
resource
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]:
Failed to instantiate
[org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Factory method
'mongoTemplate' threw exception with message: Timed out after 30000 ms
while waiting for a server that matches
com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$xxxxxxxx.

I established a VPC end point connection with MongoDB atlas in ap-southeast-2 region. Initially when I used the mongoDB connection string in springBoot application, It works fine when deployed in AWS Elastic Beanstalk. But now it is working, I'm getting HTTP 404 error. When I replaced the Private end point url with public url of that database, it is working fine. Can anyone help me with this?

This sounds more like a network issue than a programming one.
